# Stata twoway line graph with no end connections

Tags: graph, line, stata

I have two countries for two variables.

The ends of each country's set of data should not be connected to the starting point of another country's data - I can`t figure out how to prevent this behaviour.

```
twoway (line bspDiff Year if Countryshort == "China" | Countryshort == "India") (line hdiDiff Year if Countryshort == "China" | Countryshort == "India", xlabel(1980(1)2013, labsize(tiny)))
```

[Link to how the graph looks like ...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Bs9goZ1liET2JPaExzVk9MM2s/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just two countries, it is worth the small amount of extra code to make lines look different:

```
twoway line bspDiff Year if Countryshort == "China", lc(blue)  || line bspDiff year if  Countryshort == "India", lc(red) || line hdiDiff Year if Countryshort == "China", lc(blue) lp(dash) || line hdiDiff Year if Countryshort == "India", lc(red) lp(dash) xlabel(1980(5)2010) xtick(1980/2013)
```

There is nothing of importance beyond personal style preference in my using `||` rather than the `()` syntax.

I've added token options to show how to control line colours and patterns.

Side-details: A legend springs into being with `graph` calls like this. It's a matter of taste to edit the default text or suppress the legends altogether. Text like "China" or "India" on the graph at suitable positions is often much, much better than a legend.

I've edited the code for labelling the *x* axis. It's again a matter of taste, but it's a bit of an insult to the intelligence of your readers to imply that they can't interpolate easily to identify particular years.

A short answer to the main question here is to try `connect(L)` with a suitable sort order (e.g. `sort countryshort year`) which ensures that there is a connection if and only if the *x* axis variable is increasing.  With separate lines for separate panels that is no longer needed.

Comment: thanks a lot - 
sort(Countryshort Year) connect(L) - 
no more line end connections!